# Наследование generic-класса от интерфейса

Tags: c#, .net, наследование

У меня есть классы и интерфейсы:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Entity : IEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public interface IEntityListViewModel
{
    RangeObservableCollection<IEntity> Items { get; set; }
    IEntity SelectedItem { get; set; }

    void LoadItems();
}
```

Теперь мне нужен такой класс:

```
public abstract class EntityListViewModel<T> : IEntityListViewModel where T :  IEntity
{
    public RangeObservableCollection<T> Items { get; set; }
    public T SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public EntityListViewModel()
    {
        Items = new RangeObservableCollection<T>();
    }

    protected abstract List<T> GetEntities();

    public void LoadItems()
    {
        var lst = GetEntities();
        Items.ReplaceRange(lst);
    }
}
```

Естественно, компилятор требует реализации RangeObservableCollection.Items

Я бы мог сделать так:

```
public interface IEntityListViewModel<T> where T : IEntity
{
    RangeObservableCollection<T> Items { get; set; }
    T SelectedItem { get; set; }

    void LoadItems();
}
```

Но у меня есть еще один класс:

```
public abstract class UserControlBase : UserControl
{
    public IEntityListViewModel VM { get; set; }        

    public virtual void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VM.LoadItems();
    }        
}
```

А дальше уже конкретные UserControl'ы наследуются от UserControlBase. Для чего это мне? В UserControl'ах куча повторяющегося кода (в основном привязки событий ViewModel). Поэтому это все я хочу сделать в UserControlBase. Я бы мог объявить в UserControlBase так:

```
public IEntityListViewModel<T> VM { get; set; }
```

но тогда мне T нужно поднимать в UserControlBase, а это как-то криво.

Как мне наследовать EntityListViewModel от обычного IEntityListViewModel? Или есть какое-то другое решение?

UPD 1:
Явно реализовал, как посоветовали в комментариях:

```
public abstract class EntityListViewModel<T> : IEntityListViewModel where T :  IEntity
{
    public RangeObservableCollection<T> Items { get; set; }
    public T SelectedItem { get; set; }
    RangeObservableCollection<IEntity> IEntityListViewModel.Items { get; set; }
    IEntity IEntityListViewModel.SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public EntityListViewModel()
    {
        Items = new RangeObservableCollection<T>();
    }

    protected abstract List<T> GetEntities();

    public void LoadItems()
    {
        var lst = GetEntities();
        Items.ReplaceRange(lst);
    }
}
```

Но теперь во View вызов VM.Items обращается к IEntityListViewModel.Items

Comment: что мешает явно реализовать это свойство?

Comment: Это у вас WinForms или WPF? Непонятно, почему вам вдруг понадобилось привязываться к событиям VM.

Comment: WPF. А как без привязки к событиям в VM? Например есть событие Action <string> ErrorOccured, оно случается во ViewModel, а View должен как-то отреагировать (показать MessageBox, например).

Comment: @AndrewK: Не-не, вы делаете что-то не так. VM обычно выставляет INPC, View реагирует через Binding. Вы должны стараться во View вовсе не знать о том, какие типы в VM.

Comment: @AndrewK: А запускать диалог с пользователем — вовсе не дело VM, это же часть бизнес-логики.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В текущем виде самым простым для вас было бы действительно объявить `UserControlBase` обобщенным. Если же этот способ вам по какой-то причине не подойдет - надо выносить хранение из базового класса в наследники.

В вашем случае, если базовый класс подписывается на события - ему нужен интерфейс `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Его и надо запрашивать у наследника:

```
public abstract class UserControlBase : UserControl
{
    protected abstract INotifyCollectionChanged AbstractItems { get; }
}

public class FooListControl : UserControlBase
{
    public IEntityListViewModel<Foo> VM { get; set; }

    protected virtual INotifyCollectionChanged AbstractItems => VM.Items;
}
```

Если при таком подходе в базовом классе оказывается слишком много полей - надо выделять в интерфейсе ковариантную часть.

Например, для ваш интерфейс `IEntityListViewModel` можно разбить следующим образом:

```
public interface IEntityListViewModel<T> : IEntityListViewModelOut<T> where T : IEntity
{
    RangeObservableCollection<T> Items { get; set; }
    T SelectedItem { get; set; }
}

public interface IEntityListViewModelOut<out T> where T : IEntity
{
    IReadOnlyList<T> Items { get; }
    INotifyCollectionChanged ItemsEvents { get; }
    T SelectedItem { get; }

    void LoadItems();
}
```

Реализовать такой "усложненный" интерфейс не сильно сложнее чем обычный:

```
public class EntityListViewModel<T> : IEntityListViewModel<T> where T :  IEntity
{
    public RangeObservableCollection<T> Items { get; set; } = new RangeObservableCollection<T>();
    public T SelectedItem { get; set; }

    IEntityListViewModelOut<T>.Items => Items;
    IEntityListViewModelOut<T>.ItemsEvents => Items;
    IEntityListViewModelOut<T>.SelectedItem => SelectedItem;
}
```

После этого, ковариантную часть можно "пробросить" в базовый класс через абстрактное свойство:

```
public abstract class UserControlBase : UserControl
{
    protected abstract IEntityListViewModelOut<IEntity> AbstractVM { get; }
}

public class FooListControl : UserControlBase
{
    public IEntityListViewModel<Foo> VM { get; set; }

    protected virtual IEntityListViewModelOut<IEntity> AbstractVM => VM;
}
```