# Объявление свойства в абстрактном классе типа абстрактного класса универсального типа с параметром типа этого класса

Tags: c#, generics, типы

Приветствую!

Есть абстрактный класс:

```
public abstract class BaseDBObject {}
```

А так же есть класс список из этих объектов:

```
public abstract class BaseObjectsList<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : BaseDBObject, new() {}
```

Вопрос в следующем:

Я хочу в первом классе иметь ссылку на список, к которому этот объект принадлежит:

```
 public BaseObjectsList<BaseDBObject> ParentList { get { return _parentList; } set { _parentList = value; } }
 private BaseObjectsList<BaseDBObject> _parentList;
```

Как я могу это сделать? Спасибо за помощь!

Добавлено:

Действительно я могу решить вопрос убрав либо ограничение new() из ограничений класса списка, но тогда я не могу воспользоваться методом:

```
protected void ЗаполнитьСписок(DataTable qRows, UDataBase pUserDB)
    {
        try
        {
            _objectsList.Clear();

            foreach (DataRow dr in qRows.Rows)
            {
                T item = new T();
                item.FillData(dr, pUserDB);
                item.DataBase = item.DataBase ?? pUserDB;
                item.DBItemStateOnPropChange();
                _objectsList.Add(item);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Который сильно упрощает жизнь ;)

А если уберу abstract из объявления базового класса объекта, то возможны ошибки при наследовании этого, класса, т.к. есть абстрактные поля, которые должны быть обязательно реализованы для каждого класса.

Идея такая, чтобы например потомок от BaseDBObject напр.:

```
public class Константа : BaseDBObject { }
```

содержал ссылку на список унаследованный от базового класса, к которому он принадлежит типа:

```
public class Константы : BaseObjectsList<Константа> { }
```

Что касается логики заполнения, то в потомке от класса с универсальным типом получаем из запроса набор строк в виде DataTable, затем передаем этот DataTable в метод ЗаполнитьСписок, который на основе строк и полей DataTable создает объекты типа BaseDBObject, заполняет поля

```
item.FillData(dr, pUserDB);
```

и добавляет его к списку.

Comment: убери абстракт из объявления свойства - и все должно работать

Comment: abstract случайно указал, конечно он там не нужен. И без него тоже не работает ;)

Comment: убери ограничение `new()`

Comment: Да, действительно об этом не подумал, но к сожалению мне оно(ограничение) нужно в связи с наличием метода в классе списке с созданием объектов этого типа(автоматическое заполнение). Можно как нить это обойти? Спасибо!

Comment: сделать статический метод, возможно даже generic, который будет создавать объект и использовать его

Comment: Попробуй добавить больше кода, чтобы было видно что и как ты хочешь использовать

Comment: Добавил, но статический метод не пойдет...есть не статичные поля, которые исп. в этом методе, а generic с указание нового типа тоже, т.к. в основе список с типом указанным при наследовании класса...

Comment: Список заполняется из DataTable, следовательно есть некий метод, который этот DataTable возвращает. Можно убрать метод заполнения списка и формировать сразу коллекцию из объектов-наследников вместо DataTable и не мучить этим вопросом абстрактный класс. Но вообще тут что-то странное с общей логикой, но пока не могу понять что именно, опишите кратко зачем такие сложные манипуляции с сущностями, какого результата ожидаете? К тому же, если имеем классы T1 и T2:T1, то List<T1> и List<T2> не образуют иерархию наследования (подставьте на место List вашу коллекцию, это не принципиально)

Comment: Ваша задача нерешаема в том виде, в котором вы его описали. Что если я сделаю так: `class EvilDBObject : BaseDBObject { public EvilDBObject(int oops) { } }`?

Comment: Гляньте вот тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/624004/178779

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас замкнутый круг: вы не можете потребовать статически, во время компиляции, чтобы все потомки имели конструктор без параметров. Но вы хотите, чтобы любой потомок имел ссылку на список, который использует конструктор без параметров.

Таким образом, задача в том виде, как она поставлена, не может быть решена. Вы должны от чего-то отказаться в вашей постановке задачи.

---

Есть несколько различных решений «с потерями».

Если вы отказываетесь от безопасности времени компиляции, вы можете отказаться от констрейнта `new()` и использовать вместо него `Activator.CreateInstance`:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in qRows.Rows)
{
    T item = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
```

При этом программа будет падать с исключением, если у `T` в реальности не будет конструктора по умолчанию.

Другое решение — допустить, что метод `ЗаполнитьСписок` будет внешним по отношению к классу, и перевести объекты, к которым он имеет доступ, в разряд `internal` или передавать их снаружи. Например, так:

```
public static class BaseObjectListHelpers
{
    public static List<T> СформироватьСписок<T>(
        DataTable qRows, UDataBase pUserDB) where T : BaseDBObject, new()
    {
        var list = new List<T>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in qRows.Rows)
        {
            T item = new T();
            item.FillData(dr, pUserDB);
            item.DataBase = item.DataBase ?? pUserDB;
            item.DBItemStateOnPropChange();
            list.Add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Вы сможете применять его так:

```
class GoodDBObject : BaseDBObject
{
}

class GoodObjectsList : BaseObjectsList<GoodDBObject>
{
    void M()
    {
        // компилируется
        _objectsList = BaseObjectListHelpers.СформироватьСписок<GoodDBObject>();
    }
}
```

```
class EvilDBObject : BaseDBObject
{
    public EvilDBObject(int oops) { }
}

class EvilObjectsList : BaseObjectsList<EvilDBObject>
{
    void M()
    {
        // не компилируется
        _objectsList = BaseObjectListHelpers.СформироватьСписок<EvilDBObject>();
    }
}
```

Comment: У него проблема еще хуже: к примеру, в GoodDBObject не получится записать ссылку на родительский GoodObjectsList.

Comment: Да, я понял ошибочность суждения и протупил с наследованием типа не как такового, а через тип универсального типа))

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ага, там даже `out` некуда приткнуть. Нужен дополнительный интерфейс `IBaseObjectsList<out T>` по идее.